# How can I deploy and anchor program using a custom RPC node url?

Tags: anchor, rpc, devnet

the normal devnet rpc is quite slow recently. How can i define a specific rpc url from lets say helius, quicknode, hellomoon or triton instead?

```
anchor deploy --url rpcurl
```

doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your endpoint in `Anchor.toml` file:

```
[provider]
cluster = "endpoint here"
wallet = "C:\\Users\\0xShuk\\.config/solana/id.json"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! But it was actually not my problem turned out. My program was deploying so slowly because my CLI was on version 1.15.1. Now that I downgraded to 1.13.8 its super fast again!